# What is the variance of the coefficient estimates for a James-Stein estimator?

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, regularization

Suppose I solve an ordinary least regression problem: find estimates for $\alpha$ and $\beta_i$ given $x_i$ and $y_i$, assuming a model $y_i = \alpha + \beta_i x + \varepsilon_i$, where the $\varepsilon_i$ are normally distributed.  I can then get confidence intervals for the $\alpha$ and $\beta_i$, shown for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Intervals).

Now suppose I wish to shrink the $\beta_i$ estimates towards zero using a [James-Stein estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James%E2%80%93Stein_estimator).  Based on [this paper "The risk of James-Stein and Lasso Shrinkage"](https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~bhansen/papers/er_16.pdf), I *think* that would be roughly

$$\hat\beta^{JS}=\beta \left(1- \frac{(p-2)\sigma^2_n}{\beta'\beta}\right)$$

where $\beta$ is an estimate for the $\beta_i$ (I skipped the hat), $\sigma_n^2$ is the true variance (I might substitute the sample variance here), and $p$ is the number of parameters in $\beta$. (I'm a bit fuzzy on whether $\alpha$ is in the newly named $\beta$.)

Finally my question: what are confidence interval estimates for the newly shrunk $\hat\beta^{JS}$?

Comment: I think to get this you would need the distribution of $\hat{\beta}^{JS}$, which is complicated because the norm operation is not invertible

Comment: Since JS is closely related to ridge regression, it's probably more fruitful to ask about CIs for the ridge estimator. I turned this up : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40509534/7281549